# Software with a lot of auto features to improve vhs quality (digital copy)?

Tags: video-editing, editor

I have copied over vhs to the computer with higher quality (more than vhs) which I will then convert to good mpeg-4.

I'm looking for a simple software with lots of automatic features to improve quality, shaking, etc. I do not expect any miracle but it's but ut should get better, and I want to be able to cut the video as well. Simple program with good and simple filters to improve recorded vhs video to digital.

Any suggestions?